# Using a variable in my code crashes my sp_send_dbmail code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So here's my code that doesn't work:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

DECLARE 
    @tab char(1) = CHAR(9),
    @arg VARCHAR(MAX) = 'N2'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'Company Profile',
    @recipients = 'randomemail.gmail.com',
    @query = 'SET NOCOUNT ON
              SELECT
                  e.EmplName,
                  FORMAT(SUM(t.ManHrs), @arg) AS [Hrs Logged to Jobs]
              FROM EmplCode e JOIN TimeTicketDet t ON e.EmplCode = t.EmplCode
              WHERE CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
              AND t.WorkCntr <> 50
              GROUP BY e.EmplName, t.WorkCntr
              HAVING SUM(t.ManHrs) < 6
              ORDER BY SUM(t.ManHrs)',
    @subject = 'Hello',
    @query_result_separator = @tab,
    @execute_query_database = 'Company DB';
```

I get the following error when I run it:

Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259..  If I remove the @arg variable inside @query and instead use

```
CAST(SUM(t.ManHrs) AS FLOAT)
```

It works fine, even leaving the declared variable, so I suppose I could do that, but I'm just wondering what the error message even means.  Any time I have quotes inside my @query argument, I'm going to have to use variables right?  So what's going on?  And how can I prevent this in the future?  Thanks

Comment: What if you try `...FORMAT(SUM(t.ManHrs),' + @arg +')...`  ?

Comment: Can't use ' ' inside @query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--Build your query outside and then send mail as below

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

CREATE TABLE Table1 (id int, EmplName varchar(10), ManHrs int)
insert into table1 values (1, 'xxxxx', 8)
insert into table1 values (2, 'xxxxx', 4)
insert into table1 values (3, 'xxxxx', 6)

insert into table1 values (4, 'YYYYY', 8)
insert into table1 values (5, 'YYYYY', 4)
insert into table1 values (6, 'YYYYY', 6)

DECLARE 
    @tab char(1) = CHAR(9)
    ,@arg VARCHAR(MAX) = 'N2'
    ,@SQLquery NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @SQLquery = 'SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT
    e.EmplName,
    FORMAT(SUM(e.ManHrs),''' + @arg + ''') AS [Hrs Logged to Jobs]
FROM table1 e 
GROUP BY e.EmplName
HAVING SUM(e.ManHrs) > 6
ORDER BY SUM(e.ManHrs)'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'Profile Name',
    @recipients = 'randomemail.gmail.com',
    @query = @SQLquery,
    @subject = 'Hello',
    @query_result_separator = @tab,
    @execute_query_database = 'DB Name';
```

Comment: Yeah, building the query outside seems like the best thing to do, thanks

Answer (score 0):

From  [sp_send_dbmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql):

> [ @query= ] 'query'
>
> Is a query to execute. The results of the query
>   can be attached as a file, or included in the body of the e-mail
>   message. The query is of type nvarchar(max), and can contain any valid
>   Transact-SQL statements. **Note that the query is executed in a separate
>   session, so local variables in the script calling sp_send_dbmail are
>   not available to the query.**

```
FORMAT(SUM(t.ManHrs), @arg)  -- @arg variable is a problem
```

So your option is to hardcode value or concatenate query string.